# pivot_wider based on condition of a 0 or 1

Tags: r, tidyr

I am trying to use `pivot_wider`  on my data. The data looks like:

```
       dates yes_no
1 2017-01-01      0
2 2017-01-02      1
3 2017-01-03      0
4 2017-01-04      1
5 2017-01-05      1
```

Where I am trying to get the expected output to be:

```
       dates yes_no 2017-01-02_1   2017-01-04_1     2017-01-05_1  
1 2017-01-01      0      0            0                 0
2 2017-01-02      1      1            0                 0
3 2017-01-03      0      0            0                 0
4 2017-01-04      1      0            1                 0 
5 2017-01-05      1      0            0                 1
```

Where the data has been `spread` when the `yes_no` column has a 1 in.

This doesn't work for me:

```
d %>% 
  mutate(value_for_one_hot = 1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = dates, values_from = value_for_one_hot,
            names_prefix = "date_", values_fill = list(value_for_one_hot = 0))
```

Data:

```
data.frame(
  dates = c("2017-01-01", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-03", "2017-01-04", "2017-01-05"),
  yes_no = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1) 
)
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me based on what you want to spread. your desired output looks somehow messy to me. is there a reason why you chose to only have three dates in the columns, not 5?

Comment: its not really a pivot-transformation, the two first columns are identical in the input and expected output... the 3 new columns in the expected output have names corresponding to selected rows from the `dates` column...

Answer (score 1):

Create a duplicate column for `yes_no` and a new column for the column names then do a normal `spread` or `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% mutate(yes_no_dup=yes_no, cols=if_else(yes_no==1, paste0(dates,'_1'), NA_character_)) %>% 
       spread(cols, yes_no_dup, fill = list(yes_no_dup = 0)) %>% 
       select(-`<NA>`)
```

Comment: On the full data I get: `Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
Keys are shared for 40 rows:`

Comment: This means you have more than one entry for some/all `dates`. What you want to do with these `dates`?

Comment: I have about 20 groups of time series data (so the dates are the same for each group). I have an event that happens for all groups on a given day. I want to create dummy variables for this day - only spreading the data for these days which has a `1` in the column. So for 20 groups, the `date` would only be spread once.

Comment: Please update `Data` to represent the actual data set.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) approach that does not actually reshape the data.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)

ind <- d[['yes_no']] != 0
cols <- as.character(d[['dates']])[ind]

d[, (cols) := 0L]
d[ind, (cols) := as.data.frame(diag(.N))]

## also valid
# set(d, which(ind), cols, as.data.frame(diag(length(cols))))

d
```