# data.table assign new columns based on variable

Tags: r, data.table

A follow-up on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59088378/pivot-wider-based-on-condition-of-a-0-or-1), can a `data.table` refer to a variable inside of the DT to create new columns?

The other question wanted to turn this table:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(
  dates = c("2017-01-01", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-03", "2017-01-04", "2017-01-05"),
  yes_no = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1) 
)
        dates yes_no
1: 2017-01-01      0
2: 2017-01-02      1
3: 2017-01-03      0
4: 2017-01-04      1
5: 2017-01-05      1
```

Into this:

```
        dates yes_no 2017-01-02 2017-01-04 2017-01-05
1: 2017-01-01      0          0          0          0
2: 2017-01-02      1          1          0          0
3: 2017-01-03      0          0          0          0
4: 2017-01-04      1          0          1          0
5: 2017-01-05      1          0          0          1
```

I wanted to update-by-reference but do not know how to make new columns based on what is in the `data.table`. That is, the LHS of the `:=` operator does not appear to look in the `data.table` environment which makes this fail:

```
## tried
dt[yes_no == 1, as.character(dates) := as.data.frame(diag(.N))]
```

> Error in eval(lhs, parent.frame(), parent.frame()) : 
>     object 'dates' not found

```
## used:
ind <- dt[['yes_no']] != 0
cols <- as.character(dt[['dates']])[ind]

dt[, (cols) := 0L]
dt[ind, (cols) := as.data.frame(diag(.N))]
## also valid
# set(d, which(ind), cols, as.data.frame(diag(length(cols))))
```

Is there a more direct way to make this work?

```
dt[yes_no == 1, as.character(dates) := as.data.frame(diag(.N))]
```

Comment: This looks like an xy problem. I might use `dt[, dt[["dates"]] := as.data.table(diag(.N))]; 
dt[, dt[yes_no != 1, dates] := NULL]` but ultimately I'd avoid creating a wide format data.table.

Comment: @Roland, I would likely never do this transformation but really, I am just curious if I am missing something. Your suggestion sounds like a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not pretty but you could do:

```
dt[yes_no == 1, 
   (dt[yes_no == 1, as.character(dates)]) := as.data.table(diag(.N))]
```